# Replicate a campaign with mailchimp api(v3) and change recipient list

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to replicate a campaign, and what I'm trying to do is to change the recipient, I know it is possible through web page but I need to do this with api. In api page there is no clue, is it possible ?

this is what it says on [api page of mailchimp](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#action-post_campaigns_campaign_id_actions_replicate), there is no parameter to send.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it IS possible.

You need to execute a curl PATCH to /campaigns/{campaignId

```
$segmentOpts = [
                        'match'=>'all',

                        'conditions' => [
                            [
                                'condition_type'=> "EmailAddress",
                                "op"=>'is',
                                "field"=>'EMAIL',
                                "value"=>$email,
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];

$result = $this->getApi()->patch("campaigns/$campaignId", [
            'type' => 'regular',
            'settings' => $settings,
            'recipients' => [
                'list_id' => $this->listId,
                'segment_opts' => $segmentOpts

            ]
        ]
    );
```

The above illustrates how to update the segment with a condition so that the campaign only gets sent to an individual email.

NOTE: If the campaign has already been sent, you will need to first replicate the campaign using the api, and then patch the replicated campaign, then send the replicated campaign